# Is the SharePoint 2013 REST API fully supported in SharePointOnline (Office 365)?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, rest

Is the [SharePoint 2013 REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx) fully supported in SharePoint (part of Office 365)?

Assuming I have access permissions to make REST API calls to a SharePoint subscriptions, can I safely assume that all SP2013 REST URLs and resources are available to me?

PS - I know of one example where SharePoint has functionality missing in the SharePoint 2013 API - [The OData $batch query option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903506.aspx). I'm interested in the opposite direction where SP2013 services might be missing in SharePoint Online.